# Synonym for good/productive/star employee

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

Take the following paragraph, which would be a description of a websites services.

> We want to promote and enable greater talent and potential by
>   connecting employers with employees. Whether you're a brand,
>   operator or retailer, this is the place to find your next ???????

I need a one word synonym which implies, 'star employee'.

Comment: The expressions top-performer and employee-of-the-month come to mind, but you might not want to make a statement that offers the best employees. Just top notch ones.

Comment: Why not just "star"? It can be used to mean "person of great value or talent".

Comment: This is the place to find your next "moneymaker." "moneymaker" is defined as a thing or peron that is or might be profitable. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moneymaker

Comment: Employee of the month.

Comment: The boss's nephew.

Comment: Perhaps "superstar" or "top performer". Or actually "star employee". Does it really need to be only one word?

Comment: top performer / superstar, is more what I'm looking for. TY

Comment: @AdamC I'm unsure what sort of companies/employers you are hoping to attract, but be careful not to overplay the talents of prospective employees. Most employers want someone who is able to work within a team and be an effective communicator/negotiator. Superstars usually have big egos and expect to be able to tell everyone else what to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Rock-Star*](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/work/7-traits-rock-star-employees.html) for the last few years has indicated an employee who top the charts, so to speak.  From the referenced article, the traits of a Rock-Star are:

1. They Take Initiative
2. They Have Integrity
3. They Deliver results
4. They Communicate Well
5. They’re Adaptable
6. They Don’t Create Drama
7. They Have Passion

Comment: Also, [superstar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superstar) may fit well in the example phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***[Stakhanovite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stakhanovite)***:

> - An exceptionally hard-working or zealous person:
>
>   - *[as a modifier]: she was a Stakhanovite worker in the field of female suffering*.

(ODO)

Answer (score 0):

**trailblazer** (noun):

- A person who is the first to do something: an [innovator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/innovator)

> *'he was a trailblazer for many ideas that are now standard fare'*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trailblazer)

- A pioneer in any field of endeavor

> *'a trailblazer in science'*

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trailblazer?)

Answer (score 0):

**Linchpin** An indispensable or irreplaceable person.

The M-W Dictionary definition for **Linchpin**:a person or thing that holds something together

I first came across this term for such an employee in *Linchpin: are you Indispensable*, a book written by Seth Godin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emphasize the youth as well as the star potential then there is the loan-word from German - [*Wunderkind*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+wunderkind).  Allegedly [first used](http://www.theawl.com/2014/01/better-than-ezra) in English by George Bernard Shaw.

This is often used in the press to describe someone who achieves notable success early in life.

For example: Mark Zuckerberg is often referred to by the press as a Wunderkind, such as [here](http://www.newsmax.com/Finance/StreetTalk/Zuckerberg-Facebook-wunderkind-30/2014/05/14/id/571371/).